# Is there a way to check if a string contains a date of unknown format?

Tags: python, date, parsing, date-parsing

In Python, Is there a way to definitively check if a string contains a date.? It would be preferable if it could catch any date format, but, if not, could it catch the %B-%w-%Y format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dateutil.parser module which will parse any human readable date format for you from a string.

http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c

Comment: Note, however, that this method has a lot of false positives, e.g: `"4"` will be considered a date. Also, dates with extra content are not parsed, e.g: `"Today is 26/03/19"` is not considered a date.